# How to check if there are more than two values in my list that are different from 0?

Tags: python, list, function

How can I create a function that returns `True` if there are 2 or more items in my list that are different from `0` and returns `False` if there are fewer than 2 items in my list that aren't `0`?

(Incorrect code so you get the idea)

```
list=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 , 4]
def checker:
    if > 2 items in list are > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

How could I actually do this in Python?

Comment: Hint. Iterate. Increment a counter every time a number != 0. Return True if the counter is ever >=2. Return False otherwise.

Comment: Try:`'len(list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, lst)))`.

Comment: Also, don't name your variable `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the numbers, just count the zeroes and compare to the length of the list...

```
my_list=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 , 4]
def checker(my_list):
    return len(my_list) - my_list.count(0) >= 2 
checker(my_list)
```

Comment: You can simplify your `return`, since `len(my_list) - my_list.count(0) >= 2` is already a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

A straight-forward solution is to count the number of elements that are not 0

```py
def checker(lst):
    counter = 0
    for i in lst:
        if (i != 0):
            counter += 1
    return counter >= 2
```

A better solution is to use list comprehension:

```
def checker(lst):
    return len([i for i in lst if i != 0]) >= 2
```

Comment: you can use `list.count(0)` to count occuernec of 0 and `len(lilst)-list.count(0)` to get the counter

Comment: I know that. But I think the person that askes this question is a beginner and this is probably his or her homework problem. So I just give some straight-forward solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
def checker(l, thresh=2):
    return len([i for i in l if i > 0]) >= thresh
```

Comment: better to use `i!=0` to make it more solution centric

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 , 4]
if len([x for x in list1 if x!=0 ])>1:
     print('True')
else:
     print('False')
```

Comment: The list comprehension solution with checking for `!=0` was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61159384/2745495).

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method would simply be to use the `count` method of a `list`:

```py
def check(l):
    return (len(l) - l.count(0)) >= 2
```

Comment: Using the letter 'l' as a single-letter variable name is not recommended. Depending on the font, it can be difficult to distinguish `l` (lower case L) , from `I` (upper case i) from `1` (number 1). In many cases it is preferred to name variables according to their function, rather than single-letter, or cryptic, variable names. In the case of simple loops, traditional "looping" variable placeholders are often: i, j, k, m, n, x, y, though anything other than l`` and `o` are

Answer (score 0):

```
# your code goes here
data=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0 , 4]
def checker(data):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x!=0, data)))>=2

print(checker(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
lst=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 , 4]

if sum(map(bool,lst)) >= 2:
    print("2 or more non-zero")
else:
    print("fewer than 2 non-zero")
```